# Error 1034: converting TLF text to MovieClip for fade in transition

Tags: transition, tlf

I am trying to make text in my project fade in/out when a test button is pressed. I have gotten as far as writing the basics (I think so at least), however every time I try I click the test button, I get the following error message:

> Error Message:
>
> > TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert fl.text::TLFTextField@2de22479 to flash.display.MovieClip.   at Products_fla::Products_1/fader()

The code for the button is as follows:

> Code:

```
test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fader);

//Function: fade text
function fader(apple) :void{
clear();
TransitionManager.start(Text.Rubens, {type:Fade, direction:Transition.IN, duration:9,easing:Strong.easeOut});
}
```

I've been searching for hours now, but I only found that code from a copy/paste from the Adobe website: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Fade.html

P.S. This is my first time using stackoverflow (as I'm a newbie :) and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the end, I cached the TLF text as a bitmap on runtime, and then applied the alpha transition. This seemed to work. A bit stupid to be honest...